# Python 3: how to import a module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use Windows. Somehow I fail to import my own module.

I prepared:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\Michael\PycharmProjects\timer')
#import timer
print(sys.path)
```

An extract of what was printed:

```
site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\Michael\\PycharmProjects\\timer']
```

In C:\Users\Michael\PycharmProjects\timer I have a file named timer.py

Why is my command `import timer` incorrect?

Comment: in general put you custom paths at the front: `sys.path.insert(0, custom_path)`. There could be multiple modules with the same name in path. What is the traceback?

Answer (score 4):

Your import statement is commented out, in python you import by just doing `import timer` without the `#` in front as used by many compiled languages and their `include` statements.

Comment: Not even most, the C preprocessor is the only thing that I can think of that does that.

Answer (score 1):

The import command is flagged as a comment. Remove the hash tag and it should be fine.